# Apache poi CTProperty add new line to lpwstr custom property

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to know how to create new line(soft break or Carriage return)
in apache poi CTProperty.
\n\r and all spaciel characters not working

code:

```
POIXMLProperties properties = document.getProperties();
    if (properties.getCustomProperties() != null) 
    {
        CustomProperties customProperties = properties.getCustomProperties();
        List<CTProperty> propertiesList = null;
        if (customProperties.getUnderlyingProperties() != null) 
        {
            propertiesList = customProperties.getUnderlyingProperties().getPropertyList();
            if (propertiesList != null && !propertiesList.isEmpty()) 
            {
                String propertyName;
                for (CTProperty property : propertiesList) 
                {
                    propertyName = property.getName();
                    if (propertiesMap.containsKey(propertyName)) 
                    {
                        String lpwstrVal = propertiesMap.get(propertyName);
                        if (!StringUtil.isEmptyOrNull(lpwstrVal)) 
                        {                                               
                            property.setLpwstr(lpwstrVal);                                  
                        }
                    }
                }
```

in the property.setLpwstr(lpwstrVal) 
I need to add the new line in the lpwstrVal String

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using docx4j replacing character with breakline character